# Using CSS Grid to build a simple calculator in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been working on a simple calculator in vanilla JavaScript and in the meantime I took the opportunity to try my hand at using CSS Grid (so far I have used it very few times and I still have to improve a lot). I didn't have problems with JavaScript, but I had problems using CSS Grid.

```js
const calculator = () => {
  const doc = document,
    screen = doc.getElementById(`calculator__screen`),
    keys = doc.getElementById(`calculator__keys`);
  let operationStatus = false,
    number1,
    typeOperation;

  screen.textContent = `0`;

  if (!keys) return;
  keys.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
    const t = e.target,
      d = t.dataset;

    if (d.number) {
      writeScreen(d.number);
    }

    if (d.math) {
      getOperation(t, d.math);
    }

    if (d.operation) {
      runOperation(d.operation);
    }
  });
  const writeScreen = (number) => {
    screen.textContent === `0` || operationStatus === true ?
      (screen.textContent = number) :
      number === `.` && !screen.textContent.includes(`.`) ?
      (screen.textContent += number) :
      number !== `.` ?
      (screen.textContent += number) :
      null;
    operationStatus = false;
  };
  const getOperation = (element, operation) => {
    operationStatus = true;
    number1 = Number(screen.textContent);
    typeOperation = operation;
    screen.textContent = element.textContent;
  };
  const runOperation = (operation) => {
    operation === `clear` ?
      (screen.textContent = `0`) :
      getResult(number1, typeOperation);
    operationStatus = true;
  };
  const getResult = (number1, typeOperation) => {
    const number2 = Number(screen.textContent);
    let result;
    switch (typeOperation) {
      case `add`:
        result = number1 + number2;
        break;

      case `minus`:
        result = number1 - number2;
        break;

      case `multiply`:
        result = number1 * number2;
        break;

      case `divide`:
        result = number1 / number2;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    result === Infinity ?
      (screen.textContent = `Error`) :
      (screen.textContent = result);
  };
};

window.addEventListener(`load`, () => {
  calculator();
});
```

```css
/*Variables*/

:root {
  --body-bg: #fbfbfe;
  --black: #000;
  --white: #fff;
}


/*Base*/

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*::after,
*::before {
  content: "";
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

li,
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/*Calculator*/

.calculator {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 25rem;
  width: 90%;
}

.calculator__keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
   :first-child {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
  }
}

.calculator button {
  border: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

[data-math="add"],
[data-operation="equals"] {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

[data-number="0"] {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

[data-operation="clear"] {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.calculator__screen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: var(--white);
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator__screen" id="calculator__screen">

  </div>
  <div class="calculator__keys" id="calculator__keys">
    <button data-operation="clear">

    </button>
    <button data-operation="clear">
      C
    </button>
    <button data-math="divide">
      /
    </button>
    <button data-math="multiply">
      *
    </button>
    <button data-math="minus">
      -
    </button>
    <button data-number="7">
      7
    </button>
    <button data-number="8">
      8
    </button>
    <button data-number="9">
      9
    </button>
    <button data-math="add">
      +
    </button>
    <button data-number="4">
      4
    </button>
    <button data-number="5">
      5
    </button>
    <button data-number="6">
      6
    </button>
    <button data-number="1">
      1
    </button>
    <button data-number="2">
      2
    </button>
    <button data-number="3">
      3
    </button>
    <button data-operation="equals">
      =
    </button>
    <button data-number="0">
      0
    </button>
    <button data-number=".">
      .
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/AlessandroReina/pen/wvWaJyw

If you take a look at it, you will see a white cell next to the clear key (C); I really don't understand what is generating this empty cell. Also, my intention was to place the "-" keys "+" and "=" on the right side of my calculator, but I do not know why, they are positioned on the left side instead.

Could any of you take a look at my project and tell me where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance to anyone of you who will help me.

Best regards

Alessandro

Comment: Please add your code right here in your question, not in an external code site. Click "edit" below your post, then click the `<>` button.

Comment: Why do you have 2 buttons with `data-operation="clear"`? Also, what sense does this make `*::after,
*::before {
  content: "";
}`?

Comment: Hi connexo, first of all thank you for your reply
I entered *::after, *::before { content: ""; } among my basic styles because since every after or before pseudo element needs a content property even if empty, if I had to insert some pseudo element in my project, I would have avoided writing content: ""; every time

Comment: That's a really bad idea, because that means that **any** elements will have these now. Psueod elements should **never** be created on elements where you don't need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the code, the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-element is considered as [Grid child element](https://css-tricks.com/a-little-reminder-that-pseudo-elements-are-children-kinda/). You have defined global styles for the pseudo element with empty content which is messing up the structure.

```
*::after,
*::before {
  content: "";
}
```

As @connexo mentions that you need to delete the above or but if you need them for any reason: You can override the global style by setting individual styles for the pseudo elements:

```
.calculator__screen::after,
.calculator__screen::before {
  display: none;
}

.calculator__keys::after,
.calculator__keys::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
const calculator = () => {
  const doc = document,
    screen = doc.getElementById(`calculator__screen`),
    keys = doc.getElementById(`calculator__keys`);
  let operationStatus = false,
    number1,
    typeOperation;

  screen.textContent = `0`;

  if (!keys) return;
  keys.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
    const t = e.target,
      d = t.dataset;

    if (d.number) {
      writeScreen(d.number);
    }

    if (d.math) {
      getOperation(t, d.math);
    }

    if (d.operation) {
      runOperation(d.operation);
    }
  });
  const writeScreen = (number) => {
    screen.textContent === `0` || operationStatus === true ?
      (screen.textContent = number) :
      number === `.` && !screen.textContent.includes(`.`) ?
      (screen.textContent += number) :
      number !== `.` ?
      (screen.textContent += number) :
      null;
    operationStatus = false;
  };
  const getOperation = (element, operation) => {
    operationStatus = true;
    number1 = Number(screen.textContent);
    typeOperation = operation;
    screen.textContent = element.textContent;
  };
  const runOperation = (operation) => {
    operation === `clear` ?
      (screen.textContent = `0`) :
      getResult(number1, typeOperation);
    operationStatus = true;
  };
  const getResult = (number1, typeOperation) => {
    const number2 = Number(screen.textContent);
    let result;
    switch (typeOperation) {
      case `add`:
        result = number1 + number2;
        break;

      case `minus`:
        result = number1 - number2;
        break;

      case `multiply`:
        result = number1 * number2;
        break;

      case `divide`:
        result = number1 / number2;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    result === Infinity ?
      (screen.textContent = `Error`) :
      (screen.textContent = result);
  };
};

window.addEventListener(`load`, () => {
  calculator();
});
```

```css
/*Variables*/

:root {
  --body-bg: #fbfbfe;
  --black: #000;
  --white: #fff;
}


/*Base*/

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

*::after,
*::before {
  content: "";
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

li,
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}


/*Calculator*/

.calculator {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 25rem;
  width: 90%;
}

.calculator__screen::after,
.calculator__screen::before {
  display: none;
}

.calculator__keys {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.calculator__keys::after,
.calculator__keys::before {
  display: none;
}

.calculator__keys :first-child {
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

.calculator button {
  border: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

[data-math="add"],
[data-operation="equals"] {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

[data-number="0"] {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

[data-operation="clear"] {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.calculator__screen {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: var(--white);
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="calculator__screen" id="calculator__screen">

  </div>
  <div class="calculator__keys" id="calculator__keys">
    <button data-operation="clear">

    </button>
    <button data-operation="clear">
      C
    </button>
    <button data-math="divide">
      /
    </button>
    <button data-math="multiply">
      *
    </button>
    <button data-math="minus">
      -
    </button>
    <button data-number="7">
      7
    </button>
    <button data-number="8">
      8
    </button>
    <button data-number="9">
      9
    </button>
    <button data-math="add">
      +
    </button>
    <button data-number="4">
      4
    </button>
    <button data-number="5">
      5
    </button>
    <button data-number="6">
      6
    </button>
    <button data-number="1">
      1
    </button>
    <button data-number="2">
      2
    </button>
    <button data-number="3">
      3
    </button>
    <button data-operation="equals">
      =
    </button>
    <button data-number="0">
      0
    </button>
    <button data-number=".">
      .
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi m4n0, first of all thank you for your reply

I just applied your suggestion and the problem is solved, so thank you very very much.

Comment: @AlessandroReina Glad that I could help! :)

Comment: This is the wrong approach, espcially since OP has these pseudo element styles for completely the wrong reasons. Pseudo elemens should only ever be created exactly where needed, never on a global scale.

Comment: @connexo Can you even read the answer first? Yes, his approach is wrong. I have pointed it out. But what if he really wants them globally? So I suggested him that. Otherwise, he needs to delete it. As simple as that.